# easy autocomplete is not working on class of input box

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have one input box and I have applied easy autocomplete, with the help of a class and I have added input button on clicking on that button it adds one more input box with same and I can add as many as input box but easy autocomplete is not working on all the added input box, they have the same class.

```
var options = {     
            url: function (phrase) {
                return "all_social_media.php";
            },
            getValue: function (element) {
                return element.name;
                conole.log(element.name);
            },
            ajaxSettings: {
                dataType: "json",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    dataType: "json",
                }
            },
            preparePostData: function (data) {
                data.phrase = $(".social_media").val();
                return data;
                console.log(data);
            },
            requestDelay: 400,
                list: {
                onSelectItemEvent: function() {
                }
            }
        };
        $(".social_media").easyAutocomplete(options);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can we see your code?

Comment: can you provide some code? what did you try? how did you initialize the autocomplete class?

Comment: Please provide whatever code you have tried.

Comment: please post your current code

Comment: var options = {  
   url: function (phrase) {
    return "all_social_media.php";
   },
   getValue: function (element) {
    return element.name;
    conole.log(element.name);
   },
   ajaxSettings: {
    dataType: "json",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
     dataType: "json",
    }
   },
   preparePostData: function (data) {
    data.phrase = $(".social_media").val();
    return data;
   },
   requestDelay: 400,
    list: {
    onSelectItemEvent: function() {
    }}};
  $(".social_media").easyAutocomplete(options);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution, I have to rewrite the code of easy autocomplete code at the time of dynamically generated text box

```
//create new socials and expenses fields
$("#add_socials").click(function(){
    var html_data = $('<div class="row" style="margin-top:10px;"><div class="col-md-5"><input type="text" class="form-control social_media" placeholder="Enter Social Media" name="social_media"></div><div class="col-md-5"><input type="text" class="form-control social_media_expenses" name="social_media_expenses"  placeholder="Enter Expenses"></div><div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-danger mr-1" onclick="delete_socials(this)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></div></div>');
    $(".add_social_data").append(html_data);

    // easy auto complete is not working on dynamic generate text box, need to do this again
    var options = {     
        url: function (phrase) {
            return "all_social_media.php";
        },
        getValue: function (element) {
            return element.name;
            conole.log(element.name);
        },
        ajaxSettings: {
            dataType: "json",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                dataType: "json",
            }
        },
        preparePostData: function (data) {
            data.phrase = $(".social_media").val();
            return data;
            console.log(data);
        },
        requestDelay: 400,
            list: {
            onSelectItemEvent: function() {
            // get_order_id = $("#order_line_entry").getSelectedItemData().order_id;
            // console.log(get_order_id);
            }
        }
    };
    $(".social_media").easyAutocomplete(options);
    html_data.find('.social_media').easyAutocomplete(options);
});
```

for me, it is working fine.